# React Native 'Unexpected token' error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, react-native

I am getting a 'Unexpected token' at 5:7.  Cannot understand why.

```
var Navbar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    const { dispatch, isAuthenticated, errorMessage } = this.props
    return (
      {!isAuthenticated &&
         <Login
           errorMessage={errorMessage}
           onLoginClick={ () => dispatch(login()) }
         />
       }
       {isAuthenticated &&
         <Logout onLogoutClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())} />
       }
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write it this way :

```
render: function() {
    const { dispatch, isAuthenticated, errorMessage } = this.props
    var rendered = !isAuthenticated ? (
      <Login
        errorMessage={errorMessage}
        onLoginClick={ () => dispatch(login()) }
      />
    ) : (
      <Logout onLogoutClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())} />
    );
    return rendered;
  }
```

It's a ternary operator. You can have more information on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Basically the syntax is this one : `condition ? expr1 : expr2`